# Maven Error: Could not find or load main class Xms256m

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, maven-3

I am trying to make a new web application project in NetBeans and this Erros "Error: Could not find or load main class Xms256m" happen.
then i set  Environment variables "M2" "M2_HOME" "MAVEN_HOME" "MAVEN_OPTS" and also path system variable to the directories of the Maven.
and when i use the command "mvn -version" again that error "Error: Could not find or load main class Xms256m" happen.
My OS is Win7 x64. and using JDK1.8
can any one help me with it?

the configurations are :
M2 : C:\Program Files\MavenMine\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin
M2_HOME : C:\Program Files\MavenMine\apache-maven-3.6.3
MAVEN_OPTS : -Xms256m -Xmx512m

Comment: Sounds like some configuration has been done incorrectly.

Comment: Remove M2, M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME... path is only needed.

Comment: it worked, also i should rebooted the windows.